# create a routine in python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

So I need my program to run a task every given hour of a given day, I looked for a module that could easily do it and it exists, the schedule one, unfortunately we do not have it at my company's computer and I am not allowed to install anything, so I thought of something like this as a solution

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
while True:
    if now.strftime("%d") == '09':
        if now.strftime("%H") == '18':
            do something
```

but it does not quite work as expected, if i Run the program at the schedulled time it runs normally, but if it's not, it does nothing when the time comes

what can I do?

Comment: You never change `now`... Your loop change runs and runs with the same value so all conditions will be the same. You need to change the value of `now` ***inside*** the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `now` outside the loop at the start of the program. Once running, it never changes. Set `now` inside the loop, and consider using [`sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html#time.sleep) to let this program not waste resources as much.

Comment: well silly me, i didn't notice that the now was outsid, thanks for helping and thanks for the advice with sleep, it's certainly better